# jQuery wrapping div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I need is to wrap HTML around a current div, this is what I got so far:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-placeholder="username" />
```

Needs to be rendered as:

```
<div class="placeholding-input">
  <input type="text" data-placeholder="username" />
  <label>Username</label>
</div>
```

What I got so far:

```
$.each($('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea'), function(){
    var input = $(this);
    var container = $('<div />').addclass('placeholding-input');
    input.wrap(container);
    var label = $('<label />').html(input.data('placeholder')).appendTo(container);
});
```

But that ain't working for some reason, I have no idea why.

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var container = $('<div />').addclass('placeholding-input');
```

To:

```
var container = $('<div />').addClass('placeholding-input');
//                              ^--------------------- upperCase
```

Full code:

```
$('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea').each(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var container = $('<div>').addClass('placeholding-input');
    var label = $('<label>').html(input.data('placeholder'));
    input.wrap(container).after(label);
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GJK5m/)

Comment: @onlineracoon. How can that not be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try like below,

```
$(function() {
    $.each($('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea'), function() {    
        var input = $(this);
        var container = $('<div />').addClass('placeholding-input');
        var label = $('<label />').html(input.data('placeholder'));
        input.wrap(container).after(label);
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/skram/CsGUv/

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = $(this).wrap((container = $('<div />').addClass('placeholding-input')));
input.after((label = $('<label />').html(input.data('placeholder'))));
```

Done, thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each($('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea'), function(){
    var input = $(this);
    var container = $('<div />').addClass('placeholding-input'); // not addclass
    var label = $('<label />').html(input.data('placeholder'));
    input.wrap(container).after(label);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gjzDZ/5/)**

Comment: ..mm `after` and then `wrap` is going to add the label after the div.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the syntax error in `addclass`, append the label to the div before wrapping the input.

http://jsfiddle.net/Yb9QV/

```
$.each($('input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea'),
       function(){
            var input = $(this);
            var container = $('<div />').addClass('placeholding-input');

            var label = $('<label />')
                .html(input.data('placeholder')).appendTo(container);

            input.wrap(container);
});​
```